# Excel Formula into VBA code error

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting a few errors with VBA code that I have written to convert from a formula based query.

```
Cell.Offset(0, 37).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index((Sheets("CP INFO").Range("N6:AK570")), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cell.Offset(0, 36).Value, Sheets("CP INFO").Range("N6:AK570"), 0), 1), "No SFH")
```

The error is stating unable to get the 'Match property of the worksheetfunction class.
The original formula for the above code is - 
`=IFERROR(INDEX('CP INFO'!$N$6:AK$570,MATCH(VALUE(AK4),'CP INFO'!$N$6:$N$570,0),1),"NO SFH")` SO I cannot see what is wrong with it.

The next error I am getting is with the below code.

```
Cell.Offset(0, 39).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Left(Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Left(Right(Cell.Offset(0, 24), _
Len(Cell.Offset(0, 24)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("(", Cell.Offset(0, 24))), (Len(Cell.Offset(0, 24)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", Cell.Offset(0, 24))) + 1), ""), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Left(Right(Cell.Offset(0, 24), Len(Cell.Offset(0, 24)) - _
 Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("(", Cell.Offset(0, 24))), (Len(Cell.Offset(0, 24)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", Cell.Offset(0, 24))) + 1), "")) - 1), _
Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Left(Right(Cell.Offset(0, 24), Len(Cell.Offset(0, 24)) - _
Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("(", Cell.Offset(0, 24))), (Len(Cell.Offset(0, 24)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("-", Cell.Offset(0, 24))) + 1), ""))
```

This error is relating to the find function stating unable to find the property. I'm a real novice when it comes to these functions within VBA so no doubt I am doing something wrong or missing something?

Original formula this code has come from.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(DATA2!Y4,LEN(DATA2!Y4)-FIND("(",DATA2!Y4)),(LEN(DATA2!Y4)- 
FIND("-",DATA2!Y4))+1),""),FIND("-",IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(DATA2!Y4,LEN(DATA2!Y4)- 
FIND("(",DATA2!Y4)),(LEN(DATA2!Y4)-FIND("-",DATA2!Y4))+1),""))-1),IFERROR 
(LEFT(RIGHT(DATA2!Y4,LEN(DATA2!Y4)-FIND("(",DATA2!Y4)),(LEN(DATA2!Y4)-FIND("-",DATA2!Y4))+1),""))
```

The design of this macro is to loop through roughly 3-5k rows of data and produce a report of data pre sorted. The Cell is the current row and Column A The offset is to post values in corresponding Columns if the criteria is met.

Hopefully someone can assist.

Regards
Alan

Comment: It is better practice to not use `WorksheetFunction` in vba code, but to write the code that does what the function does.  If you insist on using the function, then look into `worksheet().Evaluate`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner I have not used Evaluate before so I will read up on it. Just a quick search I have seen comments to state this is a slow method to use?

Comment: No slower than using worksheetformula.  It would be quicker to turn it into true vba and use arrays instead of referring to the worksheet.  I would take this opportunity to learn to write correct code, using arrays.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I didn't want to ask as a new question but I have setup a function to cycle through text and if the "-" char is found then it will run the loop again until it returns a final value (this is for the second if error formula). This is working perfectly apart from the final answer is keeping 1 "-" char. The final formula would be  - DrID has been set and then loops through and DrID = Left(DrID, Val -1) as the final run would give the correct value. But it is giving an error whenever I try add -1.

Comment: Ignore the comment I answered it myself after typing that by thinking of it in a different way.

Comment: If you put test data and expected outputs we may be able to simplify it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `IfError()` like that in VBA, instead something like:

```
v = "No SFH"
On Error Resume Next
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        v = .Index((Sheets("CP INFO").Range("N6:AK570")), .Match(Cell.Offset(0, 36).Value, Sheets("CP INFO").Range("N6:AK570"), 0), 1)
    End With
On Error GoTo 0
Cell.Offset(0, 37).Value = v
```

**NOTE:**

As Scott points out, the arguments of `MATCH()` also require correction.

Comment: I don't think Match can use a 2D range.

Comment: @ScottCraner what you say is true, but then you would get ***No SFH***

Comment: Yes you would get it always, no matter what `Cell.Offset(0, 36).Value` is.